# PowerShell Display Table In HTML Email

Tags: powershell

Ok, this may have been answered, but I'm new and trying to learn, so I guess I'm not "getting" it.  I have a variable that contains a table of information (I got it from a SQL query).  I can output the variable to the screen and see the table, but when I try to build an HTML email with it in the body, it gets garbled.

Here is the code:

```
# This code sets up the HTML table in a more friendly format
$style = "<style>BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}"
$style = $style + "TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}"
$style = $style + "TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + "TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + "</style>"

# This code defines the search string in the IssueTrak database tables
$SQLServer = "Blah"
$SQLDBName = "Blah"
$SQLUsername = "Blah"
$SQLPassword = "Blah"
$SQLQuery = "SELECT u.FirstName,u.LastName,u.EMail,COUNT(UserID) as Count
        FROM dbo.Issues i with(nolock)
        JOIN DBO.Users u with(nolock) on u.UserID = i.NextActionBy
        where i.Status='Open'
        group by u.FirstName,u.LastName,u.EMail
        order by Count(*) desc"

# This code connects to the SQL server and retrieves the data
$SQLConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; uid = $SQLUsername; pwd = $SQLPassword"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()

# This code outputs the retrieved data
$DataSet.Tables | Format-Table -Auto

# This code emails a report regarding the results of the retrieved data
$smtpServer = "Blah"
$smtpFrom = "Blah"
$smtpTo = "Blah"
$messageSubject = "IssueTrak Open Issues By Next Action Report"
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto
$message.Subject = $messageSubject
$message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$message.Body = "Here is a listing of open issues in IssueTrak, sorted by Next Action.<br><br>"
$message.Body = $message.Body + $html

$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($message)
```

The output on the screen looks like this:

```
35

FirstName   LastName   EMail                                Count
---------   --------   -----                                -----
John        Doe        John.Doe@blah.com                       51
Jane        Doe        Jane.Doe@blah.com                       20
```

...but the email body looks like this:

```
Here is a listing of open issues in IssueTrak, sorted by Next Action.

Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData

Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
```

...and so on.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
# Create a DataTable
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable "TestTable"
$col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Name,([string])
$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Dept,([string])
$table.columns.add($col1)
$table.columns.add($col2)

# Add content to the DataTable
$row = $table.NewRow()
$row.Name = "John"
$row.Dept = "Physics"
$table.Rows.Add($row)
$row = $table.NewRow()
$row.Name = "Susan"
$row.Dept = "English"
$table.Rows.Add($row)

# Create an HTML version of the DataTable
$html = "<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>Dept</td></tr>"
foreach ($row in $table.Rows)
{ 
    $html += "<tr><td>" + $row[0] + "</td><td>" + $row[1] + "</td></tr>"
}
$html += "</table>"

# Send the email
$smtpserver = "smtpserver.domain.com"
$from = "user@domain.com"
$to = "user@domain.com"
$subject = "test"
$body = "Hi there,<br />Here is a table:<br /><br />" + $html
Send-MailMessage -smtpserver $smtpserver -from $from -to $to -subject $subject -body $body -bodyashtml
```

Comment: I tried that, but I'm getting errors.  I shared the full code, maybe you can see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: OK, the first thing is get rid of:
`$DataSet.Tables | Format-Table -Auto`
because that doesn't do anything. 

You need to take `$DataSet` and get a DataTable, `$table = $DataSet.Tables[0]`. Once you have the DataTable use my example to manually create the $html string.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a better solution (see ref 1)

```
$DataSet.Tables[0] |select * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, HasErrors, Name, Table, ItemArray | ConvertTo-Html
```

With the ExcludeProperty we can all exclude the noisy columns from our table without the need of specify specialy what columns we want it

(1) http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2010/05/25/reinventing-the-wheel-automating-data-consistency-checks-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: FYI - the link is broken. Your solution is what I used for a quick email. I found that `ConvertTo-Html` supports aligning columns:  
`Get-Process | ConvertTo-Html -Property Name, @{L='Handles';E={$_.Handles};A='Right';W='20'}` 
Unfortunately Outlook and other email clients don't respect the `<colgroup>` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You can try (not tested):

```
$message.Body = $message.Body + ($DataSet.Tables | format-Table -auto |  convertto-html)
```

Comment: That did not seem to help, now all I am getting in the email is a list of GUID-like numbers...

Comment: this will work, but you have select the specific columns you want in your table because the datatable object includes all sorts of properties built-in, besides your custom columns.
i.e.
$table | select col1,col2,colN | convertto-html

Answer (score 3):

I use like this:

```
Import-Module C:\dbatools\dbatools.psd1

$HostName = Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
$DiskResult = Get-DbaDiskSpace -ComputerName $HostName | Sort-Object $_.FreeInGB | Out-DbaDataTable

# Create column headers of Table1
$HtmlTable1 = "<table border='1' align='Left' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' style='color:black;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;text-align:left;'>
<tr style ='font-size:13px;font-weight: normal;background: #FFFFFF'>
<th align=left><b>ComputerName</b></th>
<th align=left><b>Name</b></th>
<th align=left><b>Label</b></th>
<th align=left><b>SizeInGB</b></th>
<th align=left><b>FreeInGB</b></th>
<th align=left><b>PercentFree</b></th>
</tr>"

# Insert data into Table1
foreach ($row in $DiskResult)
{ 
    $HtmlTable1 += "<tr style='font-size:13px;background-color:#FFFFFF'>
    <td>" + $row.ComputerName + "</td>
    <td>" + $row.Name + "</td>
    <td>" + $row.Label + "</td>
    <td>" + $row.SizeInGB + "</td>
    <td>" + $row.FreeInGB + "</td>
    <td>" + $row.PercentFree + "</td>
    </tr>"
}
$HtmlTable1 += "</table>"

# Send Mail Inputs
$smtpserver = "smtp.domain.com"
$from = "Powershell Mail <" + $HostName + "@domain.com>"
$to = "<mail1@domain.com>", "<mail2@domain.com>"
$cc = "<mail3@domain.com>" , "<mail4@domain.com>"
$subject = "Disk Check for SQL Server"
$body = "Disk info for SQL Server like below:<br/><br/>" + $HtmlTable1

Send-MailMessage -smtpserver $smtpserver -from $from -to $to -cc $cc -subject $subject -body $body -bodyashtml
```

Answer (score 1):

For someone looking for a simple table,here is what i have found

add below variable first

```
$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
</style>
"@
```

You can add like below then

```
Get-PSDrive | ConvertTo-Html -Property Name,Used,Provider,Root,
CurrentLocation 
-Head $Header | Out-File -FilePath PSDrives.html
```

While reading the file,ensure you use `-raw` as a parameter like bellow

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My  | Where-Object {$_.NotAfter -ge (get-date -DisplayHint Date) } |ConvertTo-Html -Property Issuer,Thumbprint,Notafter -Head $Header | Out-File C:\Iris\Cert.html
$body=Get-Content -Path C:\Iris\cert.html -Raw
```

then while sending mail, you can do

```
send-emailmessage -body $body -bodyashtml #other values
```

**References:**
https://4sysops.com/archives/building-html-reports-in-powershell-with-convertto-html/

Answer (score 0):

generalized answer:

`$body+=($variable|Select-Object property1,property2|ConvertTo-Html)`

just use you own variables and properties.  When other people search for solutions, this is what we want to see.

Answer (score 0):

To build on user1491315 answer.

```
$html = "<table border='1'><tr>"
$tableCol = $table.Columns | select Caption
foreach($col in $tableCol){
    $html += "<td>" + $col.Caption + "</td>"
}
    $html += "</tr>"
$tableColCount = $table.Columns.Count
foreach ($row in $table.Rows)
{
    $html += "<tr>"
    For ($i=0; $i -le $tableColCount; $i++) {
        $html += "<td>" + $row[$i] + "</td>"
    }
    $html += "</tr>"
}
$html += "</table>"
```

This does the same thing but will automatically set column names.