# Powershell Hash Table to HTML

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am trying to write a very simple Powershell script that checks files in a location and then decides if any are older than 90 days. Easy but it would be good if I can use PS's send-mailmessage cmdlet to use the hash table I have created and accept the contents formatted into HTML to be use in inside a pre build email template.

I have put together the following script (with the table part lifted from another post on StackOverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263538/powershell-display-table-in-html-email):

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$Path = "Z:\dokuwiki-20140505-0\apps\dokuwiki\data\pages"
$Days = 90
$Now = Get-Date
$ExePath="TBC"

# Set up Functions

function MailSend
{
    param([string]$message,[string]$days,[string]$html)
    #$message and $html are called inside a HTML format file called Send-Email.html
    try 
    {
        # Read html test file and interpolate the variables
        $body = iex('"' + (Get-Content "$ExePath\Send-Email.html") + '"')
        # Set mail message parameters
        $messageParameters = @{
            SmtpServer = "smtpserver"
            From = "sender"
            To = "recipient1"
            Cc = "recipient2"
            Subject = "DokuWiki files have not been modified in $days" 
            body = $body
            }

        Send-MailMessage @messageParameters -BodyAsHtml
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning "Unable to send email alert: $_"      
    }
} #MailSend

# Get list of files to transfer
$FileList = Get-ChildItem  -Path $Path -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.mode -notmatch 'd'}         

if ($FileList -eq $null) 
{
    # No files to process
    Write-Host "No files found - This is probably a problem"
    exit
}

# Find the objects available using Select-Object
#$FileList | Select-Object

# Check there are files older than $Days
foreach ($File in $FileList)
{
    #Write-Host $File.Name
    $MTime=$File.LastWriteTime
    if(($Now - $MTime).Days -ge $Days)
    {
        $matches.Add($File.Directory,$File)     
    } 
}

# Create a DataTable
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable "AgedFiles"
$col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Path,([string])
$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn File,([string])
$table.columns.add($col1)
$table.columns.add($col2)

#How do I populate the table?

#How to I get it into HTML format.

# Create an HTML version of the DataTable
$html = "<table><tr><td>Path</td><td>Table</td></tr>"
foreach ($row in $table)
{ 
    $html += "<tr><td>" + $row[0] + "</td><td>" + $row[1] + "</td></tr>"
}
$html += "</table>"

#This section prints out the Hash Array to STD-OUT and is to be removed
foreach($item in $matches.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Value)
{
    if ($item.Value -ne "d")
    {
        write-host "$($item.name)\$($item.Value)"
    }
}

MailSend "This is the message that will appear inside the email body" $days $html

exit
```

I am new to Powershell but have experience with Bash and Perl plus a few others but I just can't see how to do this one.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So I suspected that I was looking at this from a BASH view point and not utilising PowerShells Objects correctly. So instead of building a hash as I would in Bash or Perl I decided to build a custome object that would hold all the data I required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So looking at this from a Powershell coders view point rather than a shell scripter I decided to build a custom object:

```
$matches = @()

foreach ($File in $FileList)
{
    if(($Now - $File.LastWriteTime).Days -ge $Days)
    {
        $match = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        $match | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Path -Value $File.Directory
        $match | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name FileName -Value $File
        $match | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name ModTime -Value $File.LastWriteTime

        $matches += $match
    }
}
```

That then allowed me to loop round the object and convert it into HTML (I could probably play around with ConvertTo-Html but I will look at that later):

```
# Create an HTML version of the DataTable
$html = "<table><tr><td>Path</td><td>FileName</td><td>ModTime</td></tr>"
foreach ($row in $matches)
{ 
    $html += "<tr><td>" + $row[0] + "</td><td>" + $row[1] + "</td><td>" + $row[2] + "</td></tr>"
}
$html += "</table>"
```

I think I might even go back and convert Path and FileName to a URL but the above answers my original question.