# Comparing Registry Keys on Two Servers using Powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I would like to compare two Servers registry keys to make sure they both match.

Something simple like this was the initial plan:

```
$remote1 = (invoke-command -computername hostname `
{Get-ItemProperty     "HKLM:SOFTWARE\VENDOR\APP\SUBFOLDER"})
$local1 = (invoke-command `
{Get-ItemProperty  "HKLM:SOFTWARE\VENDOR\APP\SUBFOLDER"})

$compare1 = Compare-Object $local1 $remote1
```

That works great for one single specified key but I have multiple keys with sub folders. I can't provide a list of the ones I want to check (and loop round) as I want to make sure nothing new has been added. So I was drawn down this route to get all the keys under a specified branch in the Registry (to get me a list):

```
$local1 = Get-ChildItem HKLM:SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\DirectShow -Recurse `
-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

So I now have an object that will tell me all the registry SUBFOLDERS on the server and I could then loop round using $local1.PSPath to give me all the paths but I noticed something in the object that was interesting:

```
$local1 | select -first 1 -prop *
```

This returns:

```
Property      : {dbl3, dbl4, dbl5, dbl6...}
PSPath        : A path 
PSParentPath  : A Parent Path 
PSChildName   : 0
PSDrive       : HKLM
PSProvider    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
PSIsContainer : True
SubKeyCount   : 0
View          : Default
Handle        : Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle
ValueCount    : 8
Name          : A Name
```

So the Object member "Property" contains what looks like an array of all the keys or is it a sub Object?

If it was a sub-object does it contain the keys values that I am looking to compare?

I could just snatch out the $local.Name member and loop round comparing using the code above and storing any differences but I just wondered if it would be more efficient to use the data that I already have if it contains the information I need?

I am hoping that someone could confirm that if I did:

```
 $local1 = Get-ChildItem HKLM:SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\DirectShow -Recurse `
-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

 $remote1 (invoke-command -computername remoteserver1 `
 {Get-ChildItem HKLM:SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\DirectShow -Recurse `
 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue})
```

When I do the compare am I actually comparing the keys and values match or just that keys exist? :

```
Compare-Object $local1 $remote1
```

To cut a long story short, I think I have all the data I need to compare that the Registry key values match (by running this):

```
$local1
```

Returns (extract):

```
Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\DirectShow


Name                           Property                                                                                                                                                       
----                           --------                                                                                                                                                       
Debug                                                                                                                                                                                         
DoNotUse                                                                                                                                                                                      
DoNotUseDrivers32                                                                                                                                                                             
Preferred                      {00001602-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71} : {E1F1A0B8-BEEE-490D-BA7C-066C40B5E2B9}                                                                                
                               {e06d8032-db46-11cf-b4d1-00805f6cbbea} : {E1F1A0B8-BEEE-490D-BA7C-066C40B5E2B9}                                                                                
                               {00000160-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71} : {2eeb4adf-4578-4d10-bca7-bb955f56320a}                                                                                
                               {41564D57-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71} : {82d353df-90bd-4382-8bc2-3f6192b76e34}                                                                                
                               {e06d8026-db46-11cf-b4d1-00805f6cbbea} : {212690FB-83E5-4526-8FD7-74478B7939CD}
```

Am I correct and does anyone know how to access individual items from the $local1 object? Taking the example above, what is a Hive? Say I wanted the "00001602-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71" value how would I get it from the $local1 object.

A point to note that the servers are running Powershell 2 while I am testing on Powershell 4 (I can't test on a Production server). I mention this as running $local1 on the v2 servers I get a different output in that the properties do not seem to be in pairs.

```
Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\DirectShow


SKC  VC Name                           Property
---  -- ----                           --------
0   0 Debug                          {}
0   0 DoNotUse                       {}
0   0 DoNotUseDrivers32              {}
0  10 Preferred                      {{00000050-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}, {e436eb80-524f-11ce-9f53-0020af0ba77...
```

Is this case where the v4 objects will do what I want but the v2 won't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well fought my way back through the tumble-weed on this one to answer my own question. I had to assume that PowerShell V2 did not contain the key values as I couldn't find a way of extracting them so to be sure I was performing a comparison of the keys and key values I went with this:

```
foreach ( $KeyPath in $RegPath )
{
    $_Path = (invoke-command {Get-ChildItem $KeyPath -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue})

    ForEach ($key in $_Path)
    {

        $local = @()
        $remote = @()
        ForEach ( $Property in $key.Property )
        {           
            if ( $Key.Name -like "*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*" )
            {
                $KeyPath = [regex]::Replace($key.Name,[regex]"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\","HKLM:")
            } elseif ( $Key.Name -like "*HKEY_CURRENT_USER*" ) {
                $KeyPath = [regex]::Replace($key.Name,[regex]"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\","HKCU:")
            } else {
                Write-Host "I was unable to set the Registry Hive path, exiting........"
                exit 1
            }

            $lentry = (invoke-command {Get-ItemProperty -Path $KeyPath -Name $Property})
            $lfound = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
            $lfound | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Path -Value $KeyPath
            $lfound | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Property
            $lfound | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Data -Value $lentry.$Property

            $local += $lfound

            $rentry = (invoke-command -computername remoteservername -Script {Get-ItemProperty -Path $args[0] -Name $args[1]} -Args $KeyPath, $Property -ErrorVariable errmsg 2>$null)

            if ( $errmsg -like "*does not exist at path*" )
            {
                $Value = "KEY IS MISSING"
            } else {
                $Value = $rentry.$Property
            }

            $rfound = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
            $rfound | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Path -Value $KeyPath
            $rfound | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Property
            $rfound | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Data -Value $Value

            $remote += $rfound

        }
        $compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $local -DifferenceObject $remote -Property Path,Name,Data
        $results += $compare
    }
}
```

You then have all the results in an $results object that can be worked on. I used the object in an HTML table similar to this [Powershell Hash Table to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536301/powershell-hash-table-to-html).

I think it would have been much simpler in PowerShell version four with no need to build $lfound and $rfound.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell v4 you can just export the registry keys at whatever point you want and then use the following to compare them:

```
$badReg = Get-content C:\Data\badReg.reg

$goodReg = Get-ChildItem C:\Data\goodReg.reg

$results = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $goodReg -DifferenceObject $badReg
```

Comment: Thanks - Yes you can in Powershell v4 but at the time I was restricted to production servers that couldn't be upgraded and we're running Powershell v2.

Comment: Understandable.  I just found this recently and thought since v4 is more prevalent now that people might want to see the updated method for comparing objects.