# How to retrieve datas from multiple oracle tables using powershell and send mail in the exact table format?

Tags: oracle, powershell

I am trying to do DB health checks with powershell script. I have automated these checks, but now i don't know how to retrieve those DB values from Oracle(The DB where i have stored these daily check's results) using powershell and then send the mail to me in the exact table format.

I know there are multiple formats to retrieve data  from SQL Server and then use send mail, But i don't seem to find any formats for Oracle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But have you tried anything yet?

Comment: How about ODBC? Setup your oracle DB as DSN, connect to it (Get-ODBCConnection) and retrieve data (Get-ODBC-Data)

Comment: I could do that. But i already created powershell scripts to automate every checks. So it would take some extra time to retrieve data using (Get-ODBC-Data). Rather it would be best, i guess, if i create a single script to automate these checks and use that same script to send mail as well.

Comment: Yes. I tried to store these DB values and display it using Dataset. While in the powershell console, output is displayed in the table format. But when i invoke Send-mail command, the mail which i gets display only the code.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263538/powershell-display-table-in-html-email